# Como usar mais de dois tipos em parâmetros de funções?

Tags: php, tipagem, parâmetros

Suponhamos a seguinte função em PHP:

```
 function parse (string $text, array $callback) {
   # ...
 }
```

Em tese o parâmetro `$callback` deve ser um *array*, mas também pode ser aceito como *string*. Como faço para que ele aceite **tanto *arrays* como *strings***?

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não coloque o tipo. PHP é essencialmente uma linguagem dinâmica, não precisa anotar o tipo:

```
function parse(string $text, $callback) {
    if (gettype($callback) == "array") echo "é um array\n";
    else echo $callback;
}
parse("xxx", array("yyy"));
parse("xxx", "yyy");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4q9KQy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qmqcbhlv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/Overloading.php).

Já gostei muito desta solução, mas a não ser em coisas muito simples e que faça muito sentido fazer assim, hoje eu prefiro criar uma função separada para lidar com outro tipo de dado.

Em PHP 8 pode usar o tipo [`mixed`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed_type_v2) para dizer que aceita tipos diferentes e assim manter a tipagem e a flexibilidade. Na prática dá na mesma, mas no futuro talvez a linguagem não aceite mais sem o tipo.

Sabendo que pode ser dois tipos diferentes pode usar um [tipo de união](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2) deixando só esses dois. Ainda exigiria um `if` para saber qual veio e a solução de funções diferentes continua sendo melhor.